# How to set a notification forever?

Tags: ios, notifications

My App is a medicine reminder and many customers asked me to implement the possibility to schedule a medicine each day, forever.

I know the number of local notification that an App can set is limited, so what would be a good way to set this kind of reminder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];` your notification, you need to set the `repeatInterval` property of the notification.

So:

`UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];`

...

`notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;`

...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

**Note:** With `NSDayCalendarUnit` the notification will repeat daily. If you want, you could use other constants for it to repeat weekly or whatever. This constants are defined in:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit

So you might want to take a look if you need other repeat interval.

Comment: This would set just one notification and repeat it each day??

Comment: Thats right, the notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit; line.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: does this will repeat forever or for a limited period?? From documentaion:
`An app can have only a limited number of scheduled notifications; the system keeps the soonest-firing 64 notifications (with automatically rescheduled notifications counting as a single notification) and discards the rest.`